# How do I move the bar with mail, calendar, etc. from the side back to the bottom in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

In Outlook, the bar with the mail, calendar, people, etc. icons used to be at the bottom; but now, it's over on the left hand side. I keep my Outlook window parked on a monitor that's in portrait orientation when it's open, so I'd like to put that bar back down on the bottom. Dragging it doesn't work, and I can't seem to find a setting to place it where I want it. Is there a way to get that bar back to the bottom, or has Microsoft gone an made one of it's annoying changes that can't be configured again?

Comment: The way we did it is gone. I do not suggest using the registry fix because that may / will go way in a feature update. New way - just get used to it.

Comment: @John, I use it for year or so. And need to apply it twice only :)

Comment: @john I don't want to get used to it! I like those icons at the bottom of the folder list just the way they were (and are again now that I've applied the registry fix). Having that bar take up the whole left side of the window takes away from the limited horizontal space offered by my portrait mode monitor. (I put my Outlook window on that monitor because of the added vertical real estate that it provides (read more items in the list).) Microsoft should stop dictating how we should have things arranged and let us configure that ourselves.

Comment: Microsoft is changing the design.  Let us hope the registry fix holds.  If not, then all of us will need to use the new way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is:

1. run `regedit`
2. navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Office > 16.0 > Common > ExperimentEcs > Overrides
3. create string value named `Microsoft.Office.Outlook.Hub.HubBar` and set value to **false**
4. restart outlook

Comment: Thanks. If it's an experimental setting, hopefully they put a setting in the UI if they intend to keep it. It's so annoying when Microsoft messes with the UI.

Answer (score 4):

Click on File, Options, Advance, and unclick the box next to "Show Apps in Outlook". Close Outlook, and when you reopen they are back on the bottom.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).